# Is there a pythonic way of shifting pandas dataframe cells to the left, while pushing out or overwriting any nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (starting_df) with nan values in the left-hand columns. I'd like to shift all values over to the left for a left-aligned dataframe. My Dataframe is 24x24, but for argument's sake, I'm just posting a 4x4 version.
After some cool initial answers here, I modified the dataframe to also include a non-leading nan, who's position I'd like to preserve.
I have a piece of code that accomplishes what I want, but it relies on nested for-loops and suppressing an IndexError, which does not feel very pythonic. I have no experience with error handling in general, but simply suppressing an error does not seem to be the right strategy.

Starting dataframe and desired final dataframe:

[image]

Here is the code that (poorly) accomplishes the goal.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_left_aligned(starting_df):
    """take a starting df with right-aligned numbers and nan, and
    turn it into a left aligned table."""
    left_aligned_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for temp_index_1 in range(0, starting_df.shape[0]):
        temp_series = []
        for temp_index_2 in range(0, starting_df.shape[0]):
            try:
                temp_series.append(starting_df.iloc[temp_index_2, temp_index_2 + temp_index_1])
                temp_index_2 += 1
            except IndexError:
                pass
        temp_series = pd.DataFrame(temp_series, columns=['col'+str(temp_index_1 + 1)])
        left_aligned_df = pd.concat([left_aligned_df, temp_series], axis=1)
    return left_aligned_df


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                       col2=[5, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
                       col3=[7, np.nan, 3, np.nan],
                       col4=[9, 8, 6, 4]))

df_expected = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1, 2, 3, 4],
                                col2=[5, np.nan, 6, np.nan],
                                col3=[7, 8, np.nan, np.nan],
                                col4=[9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]))

df_left = get_left_aligned(df)
```

I appreciate any help with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or transpose the df and use `shift` to shift by column, when the NA num is increasing 1 by 1.

```py
dfn = df.T.copy()
for i, col in enumerate(dfn.columns):
    dfn[col] = dfn[col].shift(-i)
dfn = dfn.T

print(dfn)

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   5.0   7.0   9.0
1   2.0   NaN   8.0   NaN
2   3.0   6.0   NaN   NaN
3   4.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for. It preserves internal nan values and shifts everything to the left (through some Rubik's cube like manipulations). It works perfectly on my original dataset.
Thanks!
And thanks to everyone who helped by answering!

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve your challenge is to move the data into numpy territory, sort the data, then return it as a pandas DataFrame:

Numpy converts pandas NA to object data type; `pd.to_numeric` resolves that to data types numpy can work with.

```
  pd.DataFrame(
    np.sort(df.transform(pd.to_numeric).to_numpy(), axis=1),
    columns=df.columns,
    dtype="Int64",
)

    col1    col2    col3
0     1     4       6
1     2     5       <NA>
2     3     <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I think I tend to forget about numpy to my own detriment.
Follow-up: What if my dataframe contains internal nan, whos positions i'd like to preserve? So that only the LEADING nan get removed?
Like this one:
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                       col2=[5, 2, np.nan, np.nan], 
                       col3=[7, np.nan, 3, np.nan],
                       col4=[9, 8, 6, 4]))

Comment: Kindly add it to your original question, with your expected output. Would be great if you posted the data, and not pics.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to stackoverflow. I thought the picture might help explain what I was asking.
I'll edit my original question. I also upvoted your answer, but I don't have enough reputation for it to actually show up.

Comment: oh no worries about the upvote. You could even get better answers than mine; as long as your question makes it easy for folks to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort values on the row based on their positions, keeping the `nan` values at the end, giving them a very high value (np.nan, for example), rather than their actual position.

```py
df.T.apply(
    lambda x: [z[1] for z in sorted(enumerate(x), key=(lambda k: np.inf if pd.isna(k[1]) else k[0]), reverse=False)],
    axis=0
).T
```

Here an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
    [np.nan, 2, 4, 7],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 6, 9],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
)

df2 = df.T.apply(
    lambda x: [z[1] for z in sorted(enumerate(x), key=(lambda k: np.inf if pd.isna(k[1]) else k[0]), reverse=False)],
    axis=0
).T
```

And this id `df2`:

```sh
      A    B    C   D
0   2.0  4.0  7.0 NaN
1   6.0  9.0  NaN NaN
2  10.0  NaN  NaN NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```

**EDIT**

If you have rows with NaNs after the first not NaN value, you can use this approach based on [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html):

```py
df.apply(
    lambda x: x.shift(-list(x.index).index(x.first_valid_index() or x.index[0])),
    axis=1,
)
```

An example for this case:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
    [np.nan, 2, 4, 7],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 6, 9],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, 5, np.nan, 3],
],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
)

df3 = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.shift(-list(x.index).index(x.first_valid_index() or x.index[0])),
    axis=1,
)
```

And `df3` is:

```sh
      A    B    C   D
0   2.0  4.0  7.0 NaN
1   6.0  9.0  NaN NaN
2  10.0  NaN  NaN NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
4   5.0  NaN  3.0 NaN
```